# C++ declaration of template parameter shadows template parameter error

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have the following C++ code which I am compiling as below:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cassert>
template<typename T, std::size_t N> struct A;
template<typename T> struct Base {
    T &operator [](std::size_t i);
private:
    template<typename T, std::size_t N> friend struct A;
    #if !defined(NDEBUG)
        size_t n;
    #endif
};
template<typename T, std::size_t N> struct A : public Base<T> {
    A();
private:
    friend class Base<T>;
    T a[N];
};
template<typename T, std::size_t N> inline A<T,N>::A() { n = N; }
template<typename T> inline T& Base<T>::operator [](std::size_t i) {
    assert(i < n);
    return ((A<T,1>*)this)->a[i];
}
int main() {
    A<int, 3> a3;
    a3[1] = 1;
}
```

compiled using:

*g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp && ./a.out*

and gives the following 3 compiler errors:

```
*main.cpp:7:14: error: declaration of template parameter 'T' shadows template parameter
    7 |     template<typename T, std::size_t N> friend struct A;

main.cpp:4:10: note: template parameter 'T' declared here
    4 | template<typename T> struct Base {

main.cpp: In constructor 'A<T, N>::A()':
main.cpp:18:58: error: 'n' was not declared in this scope
   18 | template<typename T, std::size_t N> inline A<T,N>::A() { n = N; }*
```

Gone through other similar errors posted here, but could not get the idea much to fix it.

---

After following all your answers there is only one error now by fixing the code with all your suggestions.

```
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;
template <typename, std::size_t N> struct A;
template <typename T> struct Base { // template inheritance, compiler errors
    T& operator [](std::size_t i);
private:
    template<typename, std::size_t N> friend struct A;
    size_t n;
};
template <typename T, std::size_t N> struct A : public Base<T> {
    A();
private:
    friend class Base<T>;
    T a[N];
};
template <typename T, std::size_t N> inline A<T,N>::A() { n = N; }
template <typename T> inline T& Base<T>::operator[](std::size_t i) {
    return ((A<T,1>*)this)->a[i];
}
int main() { A<int, 3> a; a[1] = 1; }
```

Error is:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'A< <template-parameter-1-1>, N>::A()':
main.cpp:17:59: error: 'n' was not declared in this scope
17 | template <typename T, std::size_t N> inline A<T,N>::A() { n = N; }
```

Comment: The `Base` template, parametrized on `typename T`, defines some inner template with a parameter of the same name. If this meant to be a different type, change its name. If it should be the same type as the `Base`, it does not belong in the inner template's declaration. There is no law that says that every template's parameter's name must be `T`.

Comment: Just use a different name for your inner template, e.g.:`template<typename T2, std::size_t N> friend struct A;`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's the same 'law' that says the index for the outermost loop **must** be `i`, and the next one `j`, and so forth.

Comment: I hope you never have to write `return ((A<T,1>*)this)->a[i];` in a real application.

Comment: I have corrected the code by following all your comments and now I am left out with only one error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the same name i.e., `typename T` in the outer and inner template:

Outer:

```
template<typename T> struct Base {
...
```

Inner:

```
    template<typename T, std::size_t N> friend struct A;
    #if !defined(NDEBUG)
```

Change either one to fix this.

Inner fixed:

```
    template<typename U, std::size_t N> friend struct A;
    #if !defined(NDEBUG)
```

Additionally, there's another error here:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N> inline A<T,N>::A() { n = N; }
```

`n` is undeclared if `NDEBUG` is not defined, so you might need to wrap this in `#ifdef` as well.

Comment: `n` is undeclared *only* in the case that the `#if !defined(NDEBUG)` evaluates to 0.

Comment: Or even no names for declaration: `template<typename, std::size_t> friend struct A;`.

Comment: template <typename, std::size_t N> struct A;
template <typename T> struct Base { // template inheritance, compiler errors
    T& operator [](std::size_t i);
private:
    template<typename, std::size_t N> friend struct A;
    size_t n;
};
template <typename T, std::size_t N> struct A : public Base<T> {
    A();
private:
    friend class Base<T>;
    T a[N];
};
template <typename T, std::size_t N> inline A<T,N>::A() { n = N; }
template <typename T> inline T& Base<T>::operator[](std::size_t i) {
    return ((A<T,1>*)this)->a[i];
}
int main() { A<int, 3> a; a[1] = 1; } // error

Comment: There is only one error now after fixing the code with all your suggestions (fixed code is given in the above comment). `error: 'n' was not declared in this scope` 17:59

Comment: just wrap with `n = N` with `#ifdef`: `A() { #if defined(NDEBUG) n = N; #endif }`

Comment: it is declared as `private` in your base class.

Comment: Declaring it under `private` is not a problem as it is not accessed outside of the class